# jQuery appending to list click of button

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I am trying to have an item appended when I click this button:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" id="addImageButton" 
onclick="onClickAddImage(this)"/></a>
```

To this List:

```
<ul id="cardList" class="cardList">
  <li class="ui-state-default" data-type="image" onclick="onClickCard(this)">
    Image 01 <img src="./Close.gif" alt="" onclick="onClickClose(this)"/>
  </li>

  <li class="ui-state-default" data-type="image" onclick="onClickCard(this)">
    Image 01 <img src="./Close.gif" alt="" onclick="onClickClose(this)"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery script I am using is:

```
$('#addImageButton').click(function(){
   $('.cardList').append(
   '<li class="ui-state-default" data-type="image" onclick="onClickCard(this)">Image01 
   <img src="./Close.gif" alt="" onclick="onClickClose(this)"/></li>'
    );
});
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Why do you think something is wrong? Is there anything that doesn't work as you expect? What is it and what do you expect instead?

Comment: Check the console for errors. There's nothing logically wrong with what you've got.

Comment: Put that event binding code in document.ready

Comment: well the intended append effect does not occur. And am not sure why

Comment: So, the new element is not added? Is the event handler at least executed? Did you do any debugging on your own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your appended HTML string in one line as well as `<span>` is not a self-closing tag,  you need `</span>` to close it. Also remove inline `onClick` since you've already applied `.click()`:

```
$('#addImageButton').click(function () {
    $('.cardList').append('<li class="ui-state-default" data-type="image" onclick="onClickCard(this)">Image01<img src="./Close.gif" alt="" onclick="onClickClose(this)"/></li>');
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KY8YW/)**

Comment: Thanks! adding the </span> fixed the problem. apparently <span asdasd/> does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your anchor tag like this

```
<a class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" id="addImageButton">Click</span></a>
```

And the Jquery code like this

```
$('a #addImageButton').click(function(){
   $('.cardList').append(
   '<li class="ui-state-default" data-type="image" onclick="onClickCard(this)">Image01 
   <img src="./Close.gif" alt="" onclick="onClickClose(this)"/></li>'
    );
});
```

Comment: Please don't format normal text as code an provide an explanation for your solution. Why should the OP make those specific changes? Personally I don't see any difference that changes the behavior of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$('#addImageButton').click(function(){
$('#cardList').append(
'<li class="ui-state-default" data-type="image" onclick="onClickCard(this)">Image01 
<img src="./Close.gif" alt="" onclick="onClickClose(this)"/></li>'
 );
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP try that? What's the difference?

Comment: $('#cardList') using instead of $('.cardList')

Comment: Why should make a difference? Why would element be findable via its id but not its class?